# Roundcube plugin for notes

Tags: web-apps, email, note-taking

I'm looking for a plugin to the [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/) web mailer that allows to take "arbitrary notes", and stores them either into the user's IMAP account (specific folder, preferred) or the (MySQL) database. I know both variants are possible – as noted, IMAP would be preferred and MySQL OK.

#### Requirements

- integrates into *Roundcube*, ideally in the navigation pane (where the Email and Addressbook links already reside)
- stores texts preferably to a specific IMAP folder; MySQL storage is acceptable as well.
- no cloud stuff, please :)
- allows for recording of simple notes: plain text is OK, Markdown even better.
- some organizational features (hierarchy or the like) are nice, but not mandatory
- no other "fancy stuff" needed – though I'd not reject useful features as long as they don't get "too heavy"

I've already searched all kind of "plugin registries", and even skimmed *Github* using "roundcube" as search keyword – but nothing turned up. On the other hand, I've seen screenshots where a note-taking plugin was indicated by an icon in the navigation pane, so there must be one somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you saw a screenshot of [Kolab](https://kolab.org/), that's a groupware. One part of it is roundcube for the mail part.

Comment: @sebix I'm pretty sure of that, yes (as I initially thought about using Kolab, but then decided against it for several reasons). As I've integrated some other Roundcube plugins initially written for either Kolab or iRedMail and found no issues, it might be possible for this one as well – if it's available separately.

Comment: I'm looking for this also. Have you found a solution, any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RobertRicks sadly not.