# Roundcube plugin for file storage

Tags: web-apps, file-management, cloud-storage

<sup>Don't get confused: this is no dupe of [Roundcube plugin for notes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23028/185) :)</sup>

I'm looking for a plugin to the [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/) web mailer that allows the user to upload/store/download files. I'm open to variants on how these files are stored – but would prefer variants where the files then are accessible directly from within the file system.

#### Requirements

- integrates into *Roundcube*, ideally in the navigation pane (where the Email and Addressbook links already reside)
- stores files preferably directly in the file system (e.g. in configurable location outside the web tree). Other variants might be acceptable as well – but no cloud stuff, please :) The `cloud-storage` tag on this means I wanna be my own provider, kind of a "local cloud")
- allows upload/download of files
- some organizational features (hierarchy or the like) are nice, but not mandatory
- must be restrictable (i.e. admin can define who can use it) and support quotas (I don't want any pron collection other than mine :)
- no other "fancy stuff" needed – though I'd not reject useful features as long as they don't get "too heavy" (e.g. sharing with other accounts would be a real nice-to-have)

I've already searched all kind of "plugin registries", and even skimmed *Github* using "roundcube" as search keyword – but nothing turned up. In this case, I didn't even see screenshots indication such a plugin. But technically it shouldn't be too hard to implement – so maybe it exists somewhere else and I just didn't find it?